# How to remove row and sections from UITableView Sections based on NSDictionary Data Modal?

Tags: uitableview

**Code mentioned below is for deleting a particular row**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:   (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    // You need to remove 

    NSDictionary *contact = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"contact %@",contact);

    [self.sections removeObjectForKey:contact];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.sections);

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 // crashing at above line of code and shows error message see at the bottom of the post

}   

}
```

**From the above code i am able to load UITableview correctly but my app crashes 
when i am trying to delete from commitEditingStyle: method ?**

**Error Message:** 
2013-05-13 15:13:33.353 Indexed TableView Final[1372:207]  Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046

Comment: Can you debug and show at which point is your code crashing.. ?

Comment: @AhmedZ. I have added crash point and error message in question

Comment: Are you deleting the only cell/row in tableview ?

Comment: I am using Swipe to delete feature which comes with commitEditingStyle - I have loaded my tableview with 5rows in each section and i am trying to delete it randomly

Comment: can you post the numberOfRowsAtIndexPath method..

Comment: Assertion failure usually comes when.. lets say you have populated the tableView with an array with 5 objects. then you delete and object. now you have 4 to display but array count still has 5 or table view doesnt knwo that array count has been updated.

Comment: I have checked it by NSLog(@"%@",self.sections); data is not deleted from my NSDictionary.I dont know why is it so? I am working on it.Thanks for the explanation for Assertion failure.

Comment: what does `NSLog(@"contact %@",contact);` have ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29835/discussion-between-john-and-ahmed-z)